# Runtime of GPU-based simulation unexplainable?

Tags: performance, opengl, visual-c++, gpu, nsight

I am developing a GPU-based simulation using OpenGL and GLSL-Shaders and i found that performance increases when I add additional (unnecessary) GL-commands.

The simulation runs entirely on GPU without any transfers and basically consists of a loop performing 2500 algorithmically identical time steps. I carefully implemented caching of GLSL-uniform locations and removed any GL-state requests (glGet* etc) to maximize speed. To measure wall clock time i've put a `glFinish` after the main loop and take the elapsed time afterwards.

**CASE A:**
Normal total runtime for all iterations is **490ms**.

**CASE B:**
Now, if i add a single additional `glGetUniformLocation(...)` command at the end of EACH time step, it requires only **475ms** in total, which is 3 percent faster. (Please note that this is relevant to me since later i will perform a lot more timesteps)

I've looked at a timeline captured with Nvidia nsight and found that, in case A, all opengl commands are issued within the first 140ms and the glFinish takes 348ms until completion of all GPU-work. In case B the issuing of opengl commands is spread out over a significantly longer time (410ms) and the glFinish only takes 64ms yielding the faster 475ms in total.

I also noticed, that hardware command queue is much more full of work packets most of the time in case B, whereas in case A there is only one item waiting most of the time (however, there are no visible idle times).

So my questions are:

- Why is B faster?
- Why are the command packages issued more uniformly to the hardware queue over time in case A?
- How can speed be enhanced without adding additional commands?

I am using Visual c++, VS2008 on Win7 x64.

Comment: Signal noise? 3 percent over a full frame is kinda small.

Comment: That would be the most reproducible noise ever ;) The process is on high priority, one core and the results can be reproduced with 50.000 time steps as well. Also the standard deviation in both cases is less than 2ms.

Comment: glGetUniformLocation will flush the pipeline. That is the reason why the glFinish call is faster in B. In A glFinish waits until all opengl commands previously issued are finished, while in B glGetUniformLocation will do the waiting.

Comment: @BDL I thought that glGetUniformLocation might flush the pipeline and i replaced it with glFlush, but with glFlush it is as "slow" as A. Either that is not it, or glFlush is completely ignored by the driver. Can it be, that it is ignored? Or am i not understanding glFlush correctly? - it should push commands from driver into hardware queue, right? 

The fact that glGetUniformLocation does the waiting seems logical, but it should end up being the same in total.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO this question can not be answered definitely. For what it's worth I experimentally determined, that glFinish (and …SwapBuffers for that matter) have weird runtime time behavior. I'm currently developing my own VR rendering library and prior to that I spend some significant time profiling the timelines of OpenGL commands and their interaction with the graphics system. And what I found out was, that the only thing that's consistent is, that glFinish + …SwapBuffers have a very inconsistent timing behavior.

What could happen is, that this glGetUniformLocation call pulls the OpenGL driver into a "busy" state. If you call glFinish immediately afterwards it may use a different method for waiting (for example it may spin in a while loop waiting for a flag) for the GPU than if you just call glFinish (it may for example wait for a signal or a condition variable and is thus subject to the kernels scheduling behavior).

Comment: So, if i understand correctly, you say that during the long glFinish in case A the processing of the remaining calls might not be forced that fast or some other windows-wddm scheduling or the like may interfer and cause delays? That sounds possible - any idea if sth can be done except guessing the insertion of useless commands to get the case B time or even better? Another related question would be if the wddm or driver command buffer size or update intervals can be adjusted somehow?

Comment: @Thomas: Oh I think the commands are executed as fast as possible just fine. It's just that the glFinish call itself has a high variation in the time it takes to return to caller. No, I have no idea yet on how to improve it. But I'm looking into it.

Comment: How can you actually check the time of glFinish itself? If there are other commands still in the pipeline the time for glFinish depends on their time to complete, otherwise the time taken for glFinish would depend on the time the driver and the wddm take to switch to the applications context at some time, check the pipeline and realize there is nothing more to finish. In both cases the variation is naturally rather high, isn't it? I can't imagine the glFinish itself to take more than 15ms longer in case A every single time...?